# Play a sequence of images with JS, using $timeout to schedule frames

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to prefetch images in cache client and then I want to animate those prefetched images.

My code for the prefetching:

```
$scope.prefetch=function(limit) {
  for (var i=0; i<limit; i++) {
    var date = new Date($scope.dt);
    if ($scope.fileFlag == false) {
      if ($scope.viewmodel.timeResolution == 'yearly')
        date = new Date(date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + i));
      else if ($scope.viewmodel.timeResolution == 'monthly')
        date = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + i));
      else if ($scope.viewmodel.timeResolution == 'daily') {
        date = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + i));
      }
    } else {
      date = $scope.files[$scope.files.indexOf($scope.idSelectedVote) + i];
    }

    console.log( $http.get(site_url + "mwf/" + $scope.viewmodel.dataSet + "/" + $scope.viewmodel.varName + "/" + $scope.viewmodel.region + "/" + date + "/map/?vMin=" + $scope.VMin + "&vMax=" + $scope.VMax + "&type=" + $scope.viewmodel.type + "&cmap=" + $scope.viewmodel.colorMap, {'cache': true}));
  }
};
```

then i do something like this to play those images

```
$scope.play=function(limit) {
  for (var i=0; i<limit; i++) {
    $scope.map.src= site_url + "mwf/" + $scope.viewmodel.dataSet + "/" + $scope.viewmodel.varName + "/" +  $scope.viewmodel.region + "/" +  parseInt(date)+i + "/map/?vMin=" + $scope.VMin + "&vMax=" + $scope.VMax + "&type=" + $scope.viewmodel.type + "&cmap=" + $scope.viewmodel.colorMap;
    $scope.sleepFor(500);
  }                
};

$scope.sleepFor = function( sleepDuration ) {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  while(new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration){ /* do nothing */ }
}
```

My problem is when I call `play(4)` it displays only the first and the last images and not an animation. Any idea on how can I improve this code or a different approach so I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use intervals otherwise your code will block the execution of other code

Using Angular's built in `$interval` service is the solution:

```
var playInterval;
$scope.play = function(limit) {
    var interval = 1000 / 20; //20 frames per second
    var i = 0;
    $interval.cancel(playInterval); //stop previous animations if any
    if(i < limit) {
        $scope.map.src = getSrc(i++);                   
        var cache = $interval(function() {
            if(i >= limit) {                                        
                return $interval.cancel(playInterval); //or you can replace with `i = 0;` to loop the animation
            }
            $scope.map.src = getSrc(i++);
        }, interval);
    }
};

function getSrc(i) {
    return site_url + "mwf/" + $scope.viewmodel.dataSet + "/" + $scope.viewmodel.varName + "/" +  $scope.viewmodel.region + "/" +  parseInt(date)+i + "/map/?vMin=" + $scope.VMin + "&vMax=" + $scope.VMax + "&type=" + $scope.viewmodel.type + "&cmap=" + $scope.viewmodel.colorMap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked for me i have a smooth animation now of my images

Answer (score 4):

Your `sleepFor` is an idle loop: you spin and do nothing, but you prevent any other work from being done. This is not the way in Javascript to delay work for a set period of time, or schedule a function to be run at a later time. In Javascript we use `window.setTimeout` -- and in Angular we have the convenient `$timeout` service to provide that:

```
$scope.play = function(limit) {
  for (var i=0; i < limit; i++) {
    $scope.map.src = site_url + "mwf/" + $scope.viewmodel.dataSet + "/" + $scope.viewmodel.varName + "/" +  $scope.viewmodel.region + "/" +  parseInt(date)+i + "/map/?vMin=" + $scope.VMin + "&vMax=" + $scope.VMax + "&type=" + $scope.viewmodel.type + "&cmap=" + $scope.viewmodel.colorMap;

    var nextFrameMs = 500;
    $timeout($scope.play, nextFrameMs);
  }
};
```

In your example, wherever your `$scope` is provided to you -- assuming this is in a controller, you will have some line like `module.controller($scope, ...)` -- you will have to inject the `$timeout` service to be able to use it.

Additional resources:

- [Angular's documentation on `$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)
- [MDN documentation of `window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: I have tried to apply your approach on my code it does not display an animation of my images i have tried to change the nextFrameMs variable and wait longer for the next frame but still i didn't notice any change, it does feel like it displays only the first and the last image but on my console it actually itterate through all my images. the second answer suit best my needs .

Comment: Yeah, you actually had two issues: 1) not using the `$timeout` service and 2) a logic error where you are looping and scheduling all timeouts at once. You need to keep a count of the current frame outside of the function, and have the function provided to `$timeout` access and increment the frame counter.